# Where can I find recent information about which major shareholders changed their positions in a given stock?

Tags: stocks, investing, online-data-source, yahoo-finance

Where can I find recent information about which major shareholders changed their positions in a given stock? I know that I can find information on [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/mh?s=CVX+Major+Holders) but Yahoo yahoo isn't quick at updating data. I want to find sources for this information.

1. What are the exact legal obligations to report position changes for major holders?
2. Where are these transactions reported officially?

Comment: For which country / stock exchange?

Comment: Best option is go to the stock exchange where the stock is listed. Major transactions are reported every time, under regulatory filings, they are made, it is required under law I believe. When major shareholders change then it is mostly always on the news or major financial news providers like FT/Bloomberg/CNNMoney etc.

Comment: oh, I meant mainly NYSE and NASDAQ

Answer (score 4):

For the united States forms must be [submitted electronically with the Securities and Exchange Commission](http://www.sec.gov/answers/form345.htm) , they also must be posted to company websites.

- Changes in ownership are reported on Form 4 and must be reported to
  the SEC within two business days. You can find the limited categories
  of transactions not subject to the two-day reporting requirement in
  the new rule.
- Insiders must file a Form 5 to report any transactions that should have been reported earlier on a Form 4 or were eligible for deferred reporting. If a Form must be filed, it is due 45 days after the end of the company's fiscal year.
- Since June 30, 2003, the SEC has required insiders to submit forms electronically through the SEC's [EDGAR](http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html) system. (Prior to that date, insiders could choose, but were not required, to file electronically). The SEC also requires companies that maintain websites to now post the forms by the end of the next business day after filing them with the SEC.

Comment: thank you, it is great, but does EDGAR only list >10% owners? Yahoo finance lists much less than 10% owners too. how might that work? In fact there's very few any company that has 10% at one institution. Most of them only have less than 5% max. i.e. [CVX's owners](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/mh?s=CVX+Major+Holders) down to 0.4%